# Error al cargar servidor JBoss en Eclipse Photon 4.8.0

Tags: eclipse, jboss

Buen día a todos.

Recientemente he cambiado a Eclipse Photon 4.8.0 y estoy tratando de agregar un servidor Jboss.

[image: JBoss As...]

Pero me marca el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He realizado búsquedas pero realmente no he encontrado una solución.
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continué realizando búsquedas para resolver este problema, inicialmente busque actualizaciones del **WildFly** en mi eclipse, las cuales instalé, pero esto no resolvió el problema, ya que ahora me generaba el siguiente error:

> Software being installed: JBossAS Tools 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.feature.feature.group 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129)
>   Missing requirement: JBossAS Tools Server / JMX Integration 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.jmx.integration.feature.feature.group 3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129) requires 'org.eclipse.rse.core 3.1.200' but it could not be found Cannot satisfy dependency

Como se aprecia ahora me hacia falta **org.eclipse.rse.core 3.1.200** el cual tuve que instalar manualmente.

1. Primero lo descargue de la siguiente liga: [Index of /jbosstools/static/targetplatforms/jbosstoolstarget](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/targetplatforms/jbosstoolstarget/).
2. Después realicé la instalación manual. [Eclipse: How to install a plugin manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553376/eclipse-how-to-install-a-plugin-manually)
3. Reinicie mi eclipse, volví a tratar de generar el server y listo sin problemas lo pude generar.

Les dejo la liga de Stack Overflow en ingles, es de donde saque la información que resolvió mi problema.
[How to configure jboss application server with eclipse IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505813/how-to-configure-jboss-application-server-with-eclipse-ide)

Answer (score -1):

A continuación comparto la solución que funcionó para mí y que creo es más fácil de aplicar.

En Eclipse vamos al menú Help -> Eclipse Marketplace, en la nueva ventana en la pestaña "Search" buscamos por "TM Terminal". Lo desinstalamos y aceptamos el reinicio de Eclipse. Ahora ya podremos instalar el servidor WildFly.

Comment: Hola, Pablo. Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es el español, así que cualquier pregunta o respuesta debe estar en español. Así mismo, podrías incluir en tu respuesta el porqué esto ofrece algo diferente a la respuesta aceptada hace año y medio (es para una versión más reciente de Eclipse o de las librerías? Hay algo que la respuesta aceptada omitió?)

Comment: En español por favor puesto que estás en so en español